# Gray boxes around labels in exported image (PDF, JPEG,...)

Tags: plotting, graphics, export

From time to time, when I export plots with Mathematica, the labels have gray boxes as a rectangular background. I am using *Mathematica 10.0.1 for Linux (gentoo) 64bit*.

Consider this thing I again recently ran into:

```
b = 4;
n = 55;
datai = {#, PowerMod[b, #, n]} & /@ Range[1, 80];
p1 = ListPlot[datai, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, FrameLabel -> {"x", f(x)= 4^x (mod 55)"}, ImageSize -> 450, BaseStyle -> FontSize -> 17]
p2 = Grid[{{p1}}]
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "p1.pdf", p1];
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "p2.pdf", p2];
```

These are the results for `p1` (top) and `p2` (bottom):

[image]

[image]

I am not able to conclude in what situations I obtain thsese gray background boxes. "Luckily" I found out that it appears to be a workaround to wrap the plot into a `Grid`. It seems to me that all plot commands I use `List(Line)Plot`, `(List)LogPlot`, `(List)Plot`, `(List)DensityPlot`, `(List)ContourPlot` and maybe others are affected, regardless of the options. Also, it does not matter, whether I export as .pdf, .jpeg or .png (I guess also other formats are affected) or whether I use `AllowRasterization` as an option for the plot command.

Can anyone reproduce this? Even better: Can anyone tell me what is going on? It is so easy to produce nice graphs with Mathematica, but they are usually destroyed after `Export`, so that I moved over to exporting data and using pgfplots quite some time ago. But I got puzzled again and want to know what happens here...

Comment: I encountered a similar effect with legends which should have no or white background but get a gray background when exported to PDF. Could you please add OS and version number in case?

Comment: @YvesKlett Good to know I am not the only one. Version/OS is written in the second line ;)

Comment: Eeek!  Sorry for blatant speed-reading 

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem appears only when you use some specific *stylesheets* of the notebook. To replicate the issue one can choose *standard report* from *Format*->*Stylesheets*->*Report*.

To get rid of the issue you can either use some stylesheet without a background for labels or remove the backgroud by manually changing `BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 17, Background -> None}`.

Comment: Indeed, I am using the *standard report* stylesheet. your proposed `BaseStyle` config solves the problem! Thank you very much, this is great!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (reproduced from my answer on another post on a [similar question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45362/gray-background-in-export-pdf/166002#166002)):

> I recently encountered this problem, and none of the above solutions
>   solved my problems (on version 10.3.1.0). However, I have found a
>   solution which worked for me and should be independant of version.
>
> On my version, the problem specifically occurred when using the
>   `Report` stylesheet, but vanished with the `Default` one. The trick
>   was to make a custom stylesheet that includes all of the style
>   definitions from `Report` except the offending `Graphics` cell
>   definition.
>
> To achieve this practically, I switched to the `Default` stylesheet on
>   the target notebook, opened a new mathematica notebook with a `Report`
>   stylesheet , went to *Format > Edit stylesheet* on both and clicked
>   `Report/StandardReport.nb` on the latter to load the Report's default
>   cell definitions. Then I copied all the Report's cell definitions over
>   to the Private Style Definitions for XXX.nb notebook and then went in
>   and removed the offending local definition for graphics in `Styles for
>   Input and Output Cells` as well as changing the background color for
>   `Output` to white (select the cell then *Format > Background Color >
>   White*).
>
> Graphics now have a white background for both the image and text
>   labels (an issue raised in [another StackMMA question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/116518/gray-boxes-around-labels-in-exported-image-pdf-jpeg)).
>
> This new stylesheet can then be saved Default by following [these instructions](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/29974).